# What is a MQL file, and how can I import it into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MQL file that appears to be a database creation instruction. I'm curious how I can re-create the data using Pandas dataframe.

I can read the data line by line and fill in the blanks, but I'm sure I'm missing something. I couldn't find any information on MQL (perhaps it's MySQL?). Despite the fact that it is MySQL, I was unable to import a static text version of the database into a pandas dataframe.

This is the file's introduction:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'abc'
GO
USE DATABASE 'abc'
GO

CREATE ENUMERATION all_enum = {
    NA = 0,
    far = 1,
    near = 2,
    c = 3,
    NA = 4,
    m = 5,
    f = 6,
    cardinal = 7,
    NA = 8,
    ...
    }
GO

CREATE OBJECT TYPE
[word
  demcat:all_enum;
  fmhdot:integer DEFAULT 0;
  gn:all_enum;
  lexeme:string DEFAULT "";
...
]
GO

CREATE OBJECT TYPE
[book
  book:string DEFAULT "";
  book_en:string DEFAULT "";

]
GO

DROP INDEXES ON OBJECT TYPE[word]
GO
CREATE OBJECTS
WITH OBJECT TYPE[word]
```

And then a lot of object creation calls like:

```
CREATE OBJECT
FROM MONADS= { 1 }
WITH ID_D=1 [
demcat:=NA;
fmhdot:=0;
gn:=m;
...]
```

What is the most practical method for restoring this database as a dataframe object?

Comment: No, this is definitely not mysql. No matter what database product the file belongs to, you probably need to load the file to the database first, then connect to the database and retrieve the data that way. Pandas won't be able to parse an arbitrary sql file and execute the statements there.

Comment: thanks, @Shadow, do you know which kind of SQL it is? I receive only this file without references or hints...

Comment: No, I could not figure it out. Syntax seems to be close to ms sql server, but could not find create object statement in the reference.

Comment: The programming language seems to be MQL and not SQL, see https://emdros.org/MQL-Programmers-Guide.pdf please, do not ask me what this is as this is the first time I have encountered this programming language. You need to have a chat with whoever provides you the data with.